# Delete rows after a negative value in multiple data frames

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, row, sequence

I have multiple data frames which are individual sequences, consisting out the same columns. I need to delete all the rows after a negative value is encountered in the column "OnsetTime". So not the row of the negative value itself, but the row after that. All sequences have 16 rows in total.
I think it must be able by a loop, but I have no experience with loops in r and I have 499 data frames of which I am currently deleting the rows of a sequence one by one, like this:

```
sequence_6 <- sequence_6[-c(11:16), ]
sequence_7 <- sequence_7[-c(11:16), ]
sequence_9 <- sequence_9[-c(6:16), ]
```

Is there a faster way of doing this? An example of a sequence can be seen here [example sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsCWC.png)
Ragarding this example, I want to delete row 7 to row 16

Comment: example data and a more precise description is required! `negative value` of what please? Of the row sum? or a special column in the data frame? You have to be precise in programming. And also please give minimal examples so that one can try out with working code ...

Comment: I added an example of my dataframe. Hope I provided enough information now to make clear what I mean.

Comment: Dear @laura, this is better than before but still bad: an image of a data frame doesn't help fellow programmers to try out things with your object - do you expect them to copy the data frame? - Solution: let's say your data frame's name is `df`. Then do `dput(df)` - this prints the code to create the `df` - and you copy this and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Data

Since the odd web configuration at work prevents me from accessing your data, I created three dataframes based on random numbers

```
set.seed(123); data_1 <- data.frame( value = runif(25, min = -0.1) )
set.seed(234); data_2 <- data.frame( value = runif(20, min = -0.1) )
set.seed(345); data_3 <- data.frame( value = runif(30, min = -0.1) )
```

First, you could create a list containing all your dataframes:

```
list_df <- list(data_1, data_2, data_3)
```

Now you can go through this list with a `for` loop. Since there are several steps, I find it convenient to use the package `dplyr` because it allows for a more readable notation:

```
library(dplyr)

for( i in 1:length(list_df) ){

  min_row <- 
    list_df[[i]] %>%        
    mutate( id = row_number() ) %>% # add a column with row number 
    filter(value < 0) %>%           # get the rows with negative values
    summarise( min(id) ) %>%        # get the first row number 
    as.numeric()                    # transform this value to a scalar (not a dataframe)

  list_df[[i]] <- list_df[[i]] %>% slice(1:min_row) # get rows 1 to min_row 
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

We can get the datasets into a `list` assuming that the object names start with 'sequence' followed by a `-` and one or more digits.   Then use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and subset the rows based on the condition

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern="^sequence_\\d+$")), function(x) {
          i1 <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(x, `<`, 0))
          #or use rowSums
          #i1 <- rowSums(x < 0) > 0
          i2 <- which(i1)[1]
          x[seq(i2),]
       }
      )
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
sequence_6 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(-1:10, 16 *5, replace = TRUE), nrow = 16))
sequence_7 <-  as.data.frame(matrix(sample(-2:10, 16 *5, replace = TRUE), nrow = 16))
sequence_9 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(-2:10, 16 *5, replace = TRUE), nrow = 16))
```

Comment: When running that code I get an error:


`Error in seq.default(i2) : 'from' must be a finite number 
7.
stop("'from' must be a finite number") 
6.
seq.default(i2) 
5.
seq(i2) 
4.
`[.data.frame`(x, seq(i2), ) 
3.
x[seq(i2), ] 
2.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1.
lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^sequence_\\d+$")), function(x) {
    i1 <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(x, `<`, 0))
    i2 <- which(i1)[1]
    x[seq(i2), ] ... `

Comment: @laura I provided a small reproducible example and it is working for me

Comment: @laura  Anyway, I showed an example based on the descrip[tion you provided and it works for me